# How to use a filepath as a registry key when using VBA in Microsoft Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write the path to my AddIn, into the registry using the following function:

```
Public Function RegistrySave(Key As String, Value As String, Optional RegistryType As String = "REG_SZ") As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Dim oShell As Object

    ' Access Windows scripting
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    ' Write registry key
    oShell.RegWrite Key, Value, RegistryType

    ' If no error is thrown then we know the key has been written
    RegistrySave = True

    Exit Function

ErrorTrap:
    RegistrySave = False

End Function
```

The path to my AddIn is:
 `strPath = "C:\Users\Barry Blade\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\"`

When I use the function:

```
RegistrySave("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Add-in Manager\" & strPath, "")
```

I just see a huge nested set of folders in `regedit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use this convoluted method whereas you can simply use the Addins.Add method to add an add-in to the list of avialble add-ins (which also updates that registry key):

```
With AddIns.Add(strKey)
    .Installed = True
End With
```

Comment: For whatever reason, it doesn't seem to add the corresponding registry key. I'm passing in the full file path and the AddIn name: `C:\Users\Barry Blade\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\MyAddin.xlam`

Comment: Excel only adds the entries after you close all instances of Excel.